# Installing older version of software

Tags: command-line, kdenlive

I ask for help on a software issue. My OS was recently updated to version 16.04 Ubuntu Studio. Along with the update, Kdenlive lost a capture feature via firewire (capture monitor).

I would like to install the previous version (0.9.10) to recover this functionality via terminal but I do not know how to do ...
Someone can give me some directions, I'd be grateful!

Answer (score 0):

As stated at [kdenlive.org](https://kdenlive.org/download/):

> Unfortunately users of Debian stable are still stuck with 0.9.10 which is **unsupported**.

Despite being unsupported, you could still get it and try to install it at your own risk from the [Debian stable repository](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/kdenlive).

Comment: Hi there @M.Becerra! Tks for replying! I've already downloaded the v.0.9.10 of kdenlive to my desktop! Was taged on "old software"... kinda.

Comment: I do not know the sequence and commands in order to install it via command line...

Comment: @Helder Coelho you can install it with `sudo dpkg -i kdenlive_16.12.2-1_amd64.deb`

Answer (score 0):

As M. Becerra has pointed out, Debian seems the only repo currently supporting 0.9.10 now. You might need to compile it from [source](http://http.debian.net/debian/pool/main/k/kdenlive/kdenlive_16.12.2.orig.tar.xz) though.

Another way could be to use [dvgrab](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dvgrab) on the commandline, the tool that Kdenlive used to capture Firewire. Strangely, dvgrab is still a dependency, even though Kdenlive doesn't seem to support it any more.

Also there is Kdenlive [community](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=265&t=131002) itself, where you might get better support.